# Condensation lemma in Devlin

Tags: set-theory

This is probably a dumb question, but I'm stuck at a step of the proof of the Condensation Lemma in Devlin's *Constructibility*.

Context: we have $X\prec_1 L_\alpha$ for some limit $\alpha$ and want to show that the Mostowski collapse of $X$ is $L_\beta$ for some $\beta\le\alpha$.

Having proven before that the formula $v=L_\gamma$ is $\Delta_1^{KP}$, Devlin says that there is a $\Sigma_0$ formula $\Phi(z,v,\gamma)$ of LST such that

$$ \forall\gamma\forall v[v=L_\gamma \leftrightarrow\exists z \Phi(z,v,\gamma)]$$
So far  so good. He then claims that if $\varphi(z,v,\gamma)$ is the $\mathscr{L}$-analogue of $\Phi(z,v,\gamma)$ (i.e. $\mathscr{L}$ is the formal version of LST, so $\Phi$ is a metatheoretic formula, and $\varphi$ is a set representing that formula), then

$$ \forall\gamma<\alpha\forall v[v=L_\gamma \leftrightarrow v\in L_\alpha \wedge L_\alpha\models \exists z \varphi(z,v,y)]$$

I'm confused by the $\to$ direction, namely how is he going from $\exists z\Phi(z,v,\gamma)$ to $L_\alpha\models\exists z\varphi(z,v,\gamma)$? That is to say, why is there a $z$ with $\Phi(z,v,\gamma)$ in $L_\alpha$. The ordinal $\alpha$ is merely a limit, not necessarily admissible, so appealing to $\Delta_1^{KP}$ absoluteness seems shady. I assume I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see it right now.

Thanks!

Comment: @AsafKaragila I can't see your answer anymore. Is that a problem on my end? Sorry to be a bother!

Comment: No, I deleted it to signal that it wasn't helpful. I just feel a bit sick this evening, and this way someone else might come by and provide you with actual help. Sorry!

Comment: Oh ok. That's no problem, hope you feel better!

Comment: It's fine. I just ate *a lot* earlier, and it's haunting me now. Such is life when you are on vacation. :-)

Comment: But $L_\alpha$ is rudimentarily closed. And being $x=L_\alpha$ is more than just $\Delta_1$ is actually $\Sigma_1(L_\alpha)$ for every limit $\alpha$, i.e. is definable in $L_\alpha$. I rather the  Jensen's approach, check https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~raesch/org/jensen/pdf/jensen_script_sept_26_2017.pdf, starting maybe from page 51 if you want all the basics or 65 if you feel like skiping steps. Here he proves it at page 71, lema 2.3.19, maybe you can read this proof and then read what you need to understand it

Comment: @edgaralonso I appreciate the link, but I'm assuming there's an easier way. This theorem appears in Chapter II of Devlin, the same chapter that introduces $L$. Rudimentary functions do not appear in that book for another 72 pages, so him suddenly appealing to fine structure seems rather unlikely.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something since there have been a couple answers and retractions, but Devlin shows absoluteness for arbitrary limit levels $L_\alpha$ in the same place he shows it is $\Delta_1^{KP}$ (Lemma 2.7).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I must have missed the notification. I've seen Lemma 2.7, but I'm not sure how that applies here.

Comment: The class $x=L_\alpha$ uniformly definable by a $\Sigma_1$ formula in limit levels of the hierarchy. I thought that was what was meant by the "uniformly $\Delta_1^{L_\alpha}$" in lemma 2.7, and if so I don't get why this doesn't solve the problem. (But then again, I don't get why Devlin exposes the existential quantifier explicitly at this point to justify via the obsolete lemma from chapter 1, so maybe I'm missing something.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Ok, I see what you're saying now. It does seem that 2.7 does the trick, although his way of arguing by introducing $\Phi$ seems quite confusing (perhaps even wrong?). Thanks for your help!